# executable within $PATH still going unrecognized

Tags: bash, path

I'm having an issue where I get the error

`bash: stp: command not found` (stp is the name of the file I am trying to execute)

Even when I have the folder that this program resides inside is in my $PATH variable. A couple of things I've already checked:

-Making sure I am editing the $PATH in the shell that I am operating. I edited the .bashrc file residing in my home directory adding `$HOME/bin` to the path. I have verified that I am in the bash shell by typing

`$ ps $$` which returned bash as the command.

-Making sure that what I added in .bashrc actually affected the path (after restarting the shell, but I have also restarted the computer since then). Typing

`$ echo $PATH` does indeed return `/home/myself/bin` as part of the path. I will note that the file of interest lies inside a folder inside of `/home/myself/bin`, but that shouldn't matter, right?

-Lastly, `/pathtofile/stp` executes the file as I would expect. Or just making sure I am in the directory and typing `./stp`.

So if it's in my $PATH variable, I edited the right configuration file for the bash shell, made sure I am running bash, have restarted the shell since then, I'm sure I'm overlooking something really trivial. I'm still pretty new to Unix/Linux (running Debian), so I don't know all the ins and outs. But from what I understand, I should be able to type `$ stp` no matter where I am and it should search through the path and find it inside of there.

Comment: If `stp` resides in `/path/to/tools/`; then try adding the following to your script before you attempt to invoke it:  `PATH="/path/to/tools/:$PATH"`

Comment: "I will note that the file of interest lies inside a folder inside of /home/myself/bin, but that shouldn't matter, right?" -- makes all the difference. $PATH is not recursive

Comment: I see. Then what is the point of adding /bin to the path if any folders I put in there are not also included? Seems like it would be a mess if you just dumped everything in bin (all the makefiles and other components). I did indeed try adding the directory itself to the path after the fact and it did work. So I guess I learned something today. Thanks!

Comment: It would be a mess indeed. So you build you code in one corner and then `sudo make install` to put the executable, libraries, etc in the correct places. (Assuming your makefile has the `install` target, of course.)

Answer (score 4):

> I will note that the file of interest lies inside a folder inside of /home/myself/bin, but that shouldn't matter, right?

It does matter, `$PATH` is not recursive.

You could move the file.
Or create a link (hard or symbolic). Probably symbolic will be less confusing:

If the file exists in `/home/user/bin/sub-dir/stp`, execute:

```
ln -s sub-dir/stp ~/bin/stp
```

Or add the new sub-directory to path

```
PATH=$HOME/bin/sub-dir:$PATH
```